# Collect both matching and non-matching in one stream processing?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to collect both matching and not matching elements of stream in one processing?
Take this example:

```
final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
final List<Integer> even = numbers.stream().filter( n -> n % 2 == 0 ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
final List<Integer> odd = numbers.stream().filter( n -> n % 2 != 0 ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Is there a way to avoid running through the list of numbers twice? Something like "collector for matches and collector for no-matches"?

Comment: See [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
final Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> parityMap = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(n -> n % 2 == 0));
final List<Integer> even = parityMap.get(true);
final List<Integer> odd = parityMap.get(false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it - how could I miss this?! ;) Especially helpful is the partioningBy combined with another collector, like so: `Map<Boolean,Map<Integer,Boolean>> infos = numbers.stream().collect( Collectors.partitioningBy( n -> n % 2 == 0, Collectors.toMap( n->n, n-> expensiveCalculation(n) ) ) );`

Answer (score 10):

If you have more than 2 groups (instead of odd and even here using %2) for example to group ints in remainder classes %3 you can use a Function:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> fun =  i -> i%3;
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> collect = a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fun));

System.out.println(collect);
//{0=[3, 6, 9], 1=[1, 4, 7, 10], 2=[2, 5, 8]}
```

Or imagine you have a list of strings which you want to group by starting char
instead of grouping matching and non-matching (for e.g. starts with a or not) 
you could do something like :

```
Function<String, Character> fun =  s -> s.charAt(0);
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("baz","buzz","azz","ayy","foo","doo");
Map<Character, List<String>> collect = a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fun));

System.out.println(collect);
//{a=[azz, ayy], b=[baz, buzz], d=[doo], f=[foo]}
```